# Calculate Normals from Heightmap

Tags: vector, graphics, linear-algebra, computational-geometry

I am trying to convert an heightmap into a matrix of normals using central differencing which will later correspond to the steepness of a giving point.

I found several links with correct results but without explaining the math behind.

```
  T
L O R
  B
```

From [this link](https://www.leadwerks.com/community/topic/16244-calculate-normals-from-heightmap/) I realised I can just do:

```
Vec3 normal = Vec3(2*(R-L), 2*(B-T), -4).Normalize();
```

The thing is that I don't know where the `2*` and `-4` comes from.

In [this explanation of central differencing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2326181/when-to-use-forward-or-central-difference-approximations) I see that we should divide that value by 2, but I still don't know how to connect all of this.

What I really want to know is the linear algebra definition behind this.
I have an heightmap, I want to measure the central differences and I want to obtain the normal vector to use later to measure the steepness.

PS: the Z-axis is the height.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From vector calculus, the normal of a surface is given by the *gradient operator*:

[image]

A height map `h(x, y)` is a special form of the function `f`:

[image]

For a discretized height map, assuming that the grid size is 1, the *first-order* approximations to the two derivative terms above are given by:

[image]

Since the `x` step from `L` to `R` is 2, and same for `y`. The above is exactly the formula you had, divided through by 4. When this vector is normalized, the factor of 4 is canceled.

(No linear algebra was harmed in the writing of this answer)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214518/discussion-between-sammi3-and-meowgoesthedog).